# Python: avoid too many files in loop

Tags: python, matlab

I have some Python programme, which consists of one large loop, where each iteration calls Matlab and does some other stuff.

Due to some issue with pymatbridge, I open a new connection to Matlab every 10 iterations. But now, after 1000 iterations I get the error `Too many open files (src/epoll.cpp:50)` and the programme crashes with `Abgebrochen (Speicherabzug geschrieben)` (meaning `Aborted (core dump written)`).
I assume that is due to the Matlab-connections.

The structure of my code looks like this:

```
matlab = Matlab(startup_options='-useStartupFolderPref -nosplash -nodesktop',log=True)
matlab.start()

for todo in todo_list:
#DIRTY HACK to keep matlab from stopping: every 10 steps create new connection
  if todo[0] % 10 == 0:
    matlab.stop()
    matlab = Matlab(startup_options='-useStartupFolderPref -nosplash -nodesktop',log=True)
    matlab.start()
    [call Matlab and do other stuff]
```

How can I avoid this error?

Remark: The issue with pymatbridge is that after some quite fixed number of calls, it just stops. See https://github.com/arokem/python-matlab-bridge/issues/255, where somebody else described the problem.
If somebody knows a solution, that would help as well.

I'm using

- Python 3.4.6
- pyzmq 17.0.0b3
- pymatbridge 0.5.2
- Matlab R2017a

Comment: While I know nothing of this module, try releasing the object from memory after you stop it: `matlab = None` or equivalently `del matlab`

Comment: Also, you might want to use the Python connector that comes with MATLAB: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab-engine-for-python.html

Comment: @Parfait: This did not work. I still get the same error.

Comment: @chris-luego: I looked into it, but I have trouble passing numpy-arrays.